# Duplicate ASIHTTPRequest.h using TWAnalyzerClient framework

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi I am using `TWAnalyzerClient` framework from [TouchWizards](https://touchwizards.com) to get heatmap data for my application. But when I import this framework to my project and do the recommended setup [here](https://touchwizards.com/help/getting-started/tracking-application/) I get a compiler message that `ASIHTTPRequest.h` is duplicated. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using ASIHttpRequest classes for communication layer in your app ? Please check in your project directory and if it it's there, delete the references from project directory as it may be clashing finding the same classes again.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already been using `ASIHTTPRequest` in your app before installing `TWAnalyzerClient`. Thus you don't need to drag and drop `ASIHTTPRequest` again from the `TWFramework Bundle`. You only need to do it if you don't have it already. That's the most common error.